# Pixel bender White to Transparent

Tags: pixel-bender

When I run the following pixel bender code:

```
input image4 src;
output float4 dst;

// How close of a match you want
parameter float threshold
<
  minValue:     0.0;
  maxValue:     1.0;
  defaultValue: 0.4;
>;

// Color you are matching against.
parameter float3 color
<
  defaultValue: float3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
>;

void evaluatePixel()
{
  float4 current = sampleNearest(src, outCoord());
  dst = float4((distance(current.rgb, color) < threshold) ? 0.0 : current);
}
```

I got the following error message:

ERROR: (line 21): ':' : wrong operand types no operation ':' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'const float' and a right operand of type '4-component vector of float' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, it sounds to me like Pixel Bender doesn't support the ternary (?:) operator. Expand it out into an if-statement:

```
if (distance(current.rgb, color) < threshold)
    dst = float4(0.0);
else
    dst = float4(current);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Pixel Bender, but I'm guessing the problem is that the last two arguments of the ternary `?:` operator must be the same type:

```
A = condition ? B : C
```

`B` and `C` must have the same type, which must be the same type as `A`.  In this case, it looks like you're trying to make `float4`s, so you should do:

```
dst = (distance(current.rgb, color) < threshold) ? float4(0.0) : current;
```

So that both of the last arguments (`float4(0.0)` and `current`) have type `float4`.